# Change font size on traitCollectionDidChange

Tags: ios, objective-c, size-classes, ios-autolayout

I am attempting to work around the stupid Apple 'no custom fonts with auto-layout' bug but I am running into issues implementing it in a way that will also work with trait collection updates.

I originally was running the code on a 0.5 delay from a delay-called function on viewDidLoad and in there it was updating the font size and font type correctly for the device.  However I learned that traitCollectionDidChange is also called during that time so I moved my code into there instead.  Now the font type is not updating but the font size is updating.

Here is my code, it is probably something stupid I am overlooking:

```
- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection{
    //[super traitCollectionDidChange: previousTraitCollection];
    //Create horz/vert vars for easier iffing
    UIUserInterfaceSizeClass viewHorizontal = self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass;
    UIUserInterfaceSizeClass viewVertical = self.view.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass;

    //Change font and font size depending on classes; really just the size but we need to set the font anyway
    if (viewHorizontal == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact && viewVertical == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact){
        agTtl_Text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:36];
        agSubttl_Text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:20];
        actBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:20];
        nAccBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:20];
    } else if (viewHorizontal == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact && viewVertical == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular){
        agTtl_Text.editable = YES; //still need this iOS 6 hack?
        agTtl_Text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:35];
        agSubttl_Text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:20];
        actBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:30];
        nAccBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:30];

        agTtl_Text.editable = NO; //still need this iOS 6 hack?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to figure this out finally.  I had to find a way to update once the animation of the transition was finished and I found the way to do that through the UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator that is passed to willTransitionToTraitCollection.  I also have to call my font method in viewDidLoad as well for the initial setup as willTransitionToTraitCollection only calls when a transition is setup and this won't run on app loading and will never run on IPad.

Here is my code now:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(setFontSettings) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

    rtnMsg = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    db = [[Database alloc] init];

    rtnMsg = [db bDoesDBExist];

    if ([rtnMsg[0] boolValue] == NO){
        [actBtn setTitle:@"Tap Here to Begin" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        bDBExists = NO;
    } else{
        //status.text = @"Found database";
        [actBtn setTitle:@"Tap Here to Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        nAccBtn.hidden = NO;
        nAccBtn.enabled = YES;
        bDBExists = YES;
        //self.navigationItem.title=@"New Patient Profile Creator";
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator{
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:nil completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [self setFontSettings];

    }];
}

- (void)setFontSettings{
    //[super traitCollectionDidChange: previousTraitCollection];
    //Create horz/vert vars for easier iffing
    UIUserInterfaceSizeClass viewHorizontal = self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass;
    UIUserInterfaceSizeClass viewVertical = self.view.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass;

    //Change font and font size depending on classes; really just the size but we need to set the font anyway
    if (viewHorizontal == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact && viewVertical == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact){
        agTtl_Text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:36];
        agSubttl_Text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:20];
        actBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:20];
        nAccBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:20];
    } else if (viewHorizontal == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact && viewVertical == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular){
        agTtl_Text.editable = YES;
        agTtl_Text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:35];
        agSubttl_Text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:20];
        actBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:30];
        nAccBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:30];

        agTtl_Text.editable = NO;
    } else if ((viewHorizontal == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular && viewVertical == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular) ||
               (viewHorizontal == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular && viewVertical == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact)){
        agTtl_Text.editable = YES;
        agTtl_Text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:50];
        agSubttl_Text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:34];
        actBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:30];
        nAccBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hobo Std" size:30];

        agTtl_Text.editable = NO;
    }
}
```